# Return and display the same form in Ajax Response

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

**Summary:**

I have an AJAX form. When I press the submit button, I want to build the same form, and return it for display again.

It's working fine if I display another form, but not with the same form.

Due to the nature of the problem I'm solving it would be convenient if I can just keep all my logic in one class, instead of having to build another controller, where all my business logic resides, and figure out how to call that controller. I'd be saving myself a lot of duplicate code.

**Specifics:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AppendCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;


class MyCustomForm extends FormBase{

  public function getFormId(){
    return 'my_custom_form';
  }

  public function buildForm( array $form, FormStateInterface $formstate, $params = NULL){

    $form['my_entity_reference_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#title' => $this->t('Description'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Description'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#tags' => TRUE,
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'target_bundles' => ['my_content_type'],
      ],
      '#weight' => '0',
    ]; 


    if( $params['someparam'] ){

      $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Submit 1',
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::firstCallback',
        ],
      ];   

    }
    else
    {

      $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Submit 2',
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::secondCallback',
        ],
      ];   

    }

    return $form;
  }

  public function firstCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

    $val = $form_state->getValue('my_entity_reference_field');

    if( empty($val) ){

      $response = new AjaxResponse();
      $selector = '.new_form_container';
      $params = [
        'someparam' => false
      ];  

      //THIS DOES NOT WORK, BUT IT WORKS WITH ANY OTHER FORM OR BLOCK:
      $content = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyCustomForm', $params);

      $response->addCommand( new HtmlCommand( $selector, $content ));

      return $response;
      
    }
    else
    {
      // Do something else here. This works fine.
    }
  }

  public function secondCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    //I never get a chance to see this happening  
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    //required but irrelevant
  }
}
```

I'm successfully loading and showing the form the first time by doing this in my theme file:

```
      $params = [
        'someparam' => true
      ];  

      $variables['show_my_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyCustomForm', $params);
```

And then of course in the template I put `{{ show_my_form }}`

Again, this works if I call another form in the Ajax callback. But when I call the same form, I'm getting an error.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

(By the way, there is a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62984/form-api-display-the-same-form-again-with-ajax-but-with-different-values-on) but it looks like they're using Drupal 7 or earlier...)

Comment: Perhaps the better solution is to create and use a service in my module. This is the additional work that I wanted to originally avoid, but in the long run it's perhaps cleaner and better to separate concerns like this.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/goalgorilla/open_social/blob/ee688831e7377f5e8fa15af9d2fa8af4bd387e19/modules/social_features/social_event/src/Form/EnrollActionForm.php, as this seems to be a very similar use case. Just a word of caution - I'm currently having problem with altering that form in its various states - which may be irrelevant for you.